# Visual studio clang - Generate map file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang, visual-studio-2019

I want to generate a MAP file in visual studio with LLVM (Clang-cl) compiler. I tried setting "-Wl,-map,output.map" in Properties->Linker->Command Line->Additional Options but I get:

```
warning : ignoring unknown argument '-Wl,-map,output.map'
```

On microsoft compiler I can set Generate MAP file to yes, but this option is not available when I select LLVM compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use /map or /lldmap option in Project property -> C/C++ -> Linker -> Command Line -> Additional Options

Then check Output Directory

Comment: That sounds pretty similar to what the OP did -- are you sure this helps with an LLVM compiler?

Comment: Yes it works well, I already tried it and successfully got a visual studio format map file.